# Finding stable sets from a graph

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, maxima-minima, integer-programming, decision-theory

I am trying to understand what a stable set is and have the following graph:

[image: graph]

What are examples of a stable set from this graph?
If possible, what is the maximum stable set of this graph?

My current understanding of a stable set if that its a set of connected vertices where no two are adjacent. Would NBJ therefore be a stable set, as they are connected and not next to each other?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "a set of connected vertices". A stable set (independent set) is simply a set of pairwise nonadjacent vertices. For example, in the given graph, $\{A, C, D, E, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, N, Q, S, T\}$ is a largest independent set.

Comment: Oh so for an independent set there doesn't have to be an edge between the vertices. How did you find the largest independent set?

Comment: That is correct. It simply means no edge between vertices. Observe that a path of length 2 has one vertex as independent set. A path of length 3 has two vertices as independent set. Your graph is a combination of these two cases.